# What is wrong with the type tool with Cambria in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, fonts, font-management

When using Cambria (included with Office for Mac 2011) in PS, I get this huge insertion bar (err...).

But seriously, in the left hand example the cursor is positioned after the number 1, and the bar reaches way below line 2! In the right example, the cursor is positioned after '2' for comparison. The type palette is shown.

Other fonts perform as expected (the insertion bar matches line height).

doh, not allowed to post images.. here it is:

[image: Character Panel in Photoshop]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cambria is a *horribly* constructed font. Microsoft created Cambria so that it would work as the default font for the latest Office application versions and MS assumes you don't use other apps.

This isn't a Photoshop issue. It's an issue with the font file and there is nothing you can do about it.

Comment: hokay, tx... it made trouble in Encore for me, whilst making menus with PS files... PS, tx for adding the image!